# Font sticking to top

Tags: html, css, fonts

When I use font Minecrafter 2.0 as logo, it stick to top (similar as vertical-align:top). For example http://oi58.tinypic.com/qovasy.jpg

When i use line-height (for example):

```
h1 { line-height: 1; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Logo leaves from area: http://i59.tinypic.com/jfuohy.png

With standard fonts all right. How to place font to center?

Comment: make a fiddle showing your problem

Answer (score 0):

May you should try to use padding-top rule, like that:

```
h1 { padding-top: 10px; }
```

Comment: Thanks, I was using similar solution - fix this font via margin